# Flushing output while program runs from bash

Tags: bash

I am not so familiar with bash scripts, so please be patient with me.

I have a little script like this:

```
readarray -t lines < <($COMMAND)
for line in "${lines[@]}"; do 
    echo $line
    theLines+="$line\n"
done
```

Surely nothing will be on `STDOUT` while `$COMMAND` not finished.

It could be an `ls -la`, `unzip` whatever.

How can I print the output of command real time?

Comment: Why not just run `$COMMAND` directly, and let its outut go atraight to stdout? Is the goal to *also* store the output in the `lines` array, or the `theLines` variable, or both, or something else? BTW, you should almost always double-quote variable references (e.g. `echo "$line"` instead of just `echo $line`). [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at spotting this and other common scripting mistakes.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Becuse later by a condition I would like to save the `theLines` into a file.

Comment: `command | tee myFile` will display real-time output of `command` and also write that output to a file. Good luck.

Comment: _Surely ..._ : This is unrelated to _flushing_.  If COMMAND produces a lot of output, it will actually delivered part of its output every time the outbut buffer is full. Another possibility is to have COMMAND writing to stdout unbuffered, in which case output is written immediately. However the **receiving** side (i.e. the fact that you use of process redirection forces to wait until COMMAND has exited. You request the variable `lines` to hold the complete output of COMMAND. Of course COMMAND needs to be finished first! Rewrite the program so that you don't need this anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't store the output in an array first. Have the loop read from the command itself. `readarray` can't finish until it had read all the output.

```
while read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
    theLines+="$line"$'\n'
done < <($COMMAND)
```

If you really want it in an array, you can add to the array in the loop.

```
while read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
    theLines+="$line"$'\n'
    lines+=("$line")
done < <($COMMAND)
```

Note also that you have to use `$'\n'` to get a newline in `theLines`. Escape sequences aren't expanded inside double quotes.

Comment: ty, I will check tomorow and accept if works, but I bet it will :)